# Terminology for numbers of the form $4k+1$ and $4k+3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology

A number which can be written as $2k$ is called *even* and a number which can be written as $2k+1$ is called *odd*. This terminology is helpful because we can write fluid English expressions like "Given any pair of coprime numbers, not both odd, we can..." or "Exactly one of these numbers can be even and the rest must be odd."

Many theorems of number theory distinguish between numbers (especially primes) of the form $4k+1$ and those of the form $4k+3$. Text discussing these classes is invariably clumsy, e.g. "Every prime of the form $4k+1$ can be written uniquely as the sum of two squares" and "Any prime of the form $4k+3$ that divides the sum of two squares must divide each of the squares individually." A major problem with this style of writing is that it invites semantic confusion about the letter $k$, e.g. $p^k$ could be read later as $(4k+1)^k$, which is generally not the intention.

I know that the phrase "congruent to 1 mod 4" avoids the problem with the letter $k$, e.g. "Every prime congruent to 1 mod 4 can be written uniquely as the sum of two squares" but that is still an unwieldy phrase for a concept that is referred to often (although admittedly not as often as "even" and "odd").

Obviously I could always make up my own "local names," e.g. "In this paper, numbers congruent to 1 mod 4 are called *green* and numbers congruent to 3 mod 4 are called *red.* Every red prime can be written uniquely as the sum of two squares." But surely someone has already done that before with these particular residue classes.

My question, then, is: are there semi-standard names in the literature for numbers (or even just primes) of the form $4k+1$ and $4k+3$ that can be used as fluidly as the words "even" and "odd"?

Comment: Gaussian-reducible and Gaussian-irreducible, maybe?

Comment: I would simply call them numbers congruent $1$ modulo $4$, respectively $3$ modulo $4$. If you start with colors, then considering numbers of the form $ak+b$ will soon get you into trouble. And for Dirichlet's theorem we want to consider integers of the form $ak+b$ with coprime $a$ and $b$, with respect to prime numbers. Not only for $a=4$.

Comment: "Every prime $\,p\equiv 1\!\pmod{\!4}\,\ldots"$ is not unwieldy, and is standard language (and avoids free-variable name clashes, as does $\,p\in 1\!+\!4\Bbb Z).\,$ It generalizes much more widely than does using ad-hoc names for residues classes.

Comment: Double usage of symbols are formally forbidden in Maths (never $(4k+1)^k$ except, obviously, when you do want to have it). When not necessary, symbols are not to be named with an adjective. For short in some papers dealing with primes $4k+1$ it could be called $(4k+1)-$prime or better $1-$prime but this would be just for the paper no more. (Sorry for bad English).

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I agree that there are infinitely many residue classes to consider and that it would be unwieldy to name all of them. But that didn't stop us from naming "even" and "odd." And there are many other categories of numbers which get names (e.g. "perfect number" instead of "number for which $\sigma(N)=2N$") so the idea of naming these two residue classes doesn't seem altogether unreasonable.

Comment: The two leading options right now are Oscar Lanzi's "Gaussian-reducible/irreducible" which have the advantage of being English but are painfully wrong when written down, and @BillDubuque's symbolic "Every prime $p\equiv 1 (\hbox{\rm mod} 4)$" which I will admit is not unwieldy when written down, but is still (in my opinion) clumsy to pronounce aloud. But Bill Dubuque argues that the "congruent to 1 mod 4" is standard language so I suppose that means that nobody else has converged on "shared ad-hoc" terms to simplify verbal discussion. Oh, well.

Comment: You can pronounce it concisely as: $\,p\,$ is $1\bmod 4;\ $ every prime $\,p\,$ that's $1\bmod 4,\,$ etc.

Comment: Of note: Wikipedia describes the 4k+1 primes as "Pythagorean Primes" [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_prime ] but there does not appear to be a corresponding name for non-Pythagorean primes.